# Obtaining Hard Drive serial number in windows server 2003

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-server-2003

Following another thread, I read that `wmic diskdrive get serialnumber` in cmd would produce the serial number for the hdd installed.

I'm getting a message:

```
ERROR:
Code = 0x80041017
Description = Invalid query
```

Is there another command or another way of getting the serial number (all I want to do is order a duplicate HDD) without physically going to the server?  This is a Windows Server 2003.

Comment: Serial numbers do not include model number or things like that, it's just a number which uniquely identifies the device to the vendor.

Comment: Ok, so how do I get the model number?

Comment: @awoitte `wmic diskdrive get model`

Comment: Most programs like Speccy provide information on the HDD.

Comment: @awoitte Are you running as Admin?

Comment: @DavidPostill On Windows 8, `wmic` doesn't need admin rights to look at this stuff, but it might be a different story on Server 2003. Also, OP, you should probably update.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
wmic path win32_physicalmedia get SerialNumber
```

or in PowerShell:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMedia | Format-Table Tag, SerialNumber
```

But, as mentioned in the comments, this will only get you the serial number, not the model. If you want the make/model try the following:

```
wmic path win32_physicalmedia get SerialNumber, Model, Manufacturer, SKU, ParNumber
```

Hopefully that will give you some, it depends on what they registered in the class. More options of the Win32_PhysicalMedia class can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394346(v=vs.85).aspx

Adding @DavidPostill 's suggestion as well:

```
wmic diskdrive get model
```